# Android TV (Emulator Preview, level L) - BroadcastReceiver does not work from manifest

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-5.0-lollipop, android-tv

I rely on broadcast send/receive for my app to work.

This code works perfectly on all platforms, but on latest Android Preview L, the broadcast is not received:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.my.BROADCAST_RECEIVED");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Receiver is registered in the manifest, as usual:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".SimpleBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.my.BROADCAST_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Note:** if the receiver is registered in runtime (i.e. via `registerReceiver(..)`) - it does receive the broadcast.
Any information about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a different [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23503743/1180898) related to not receiving boot complete on SmartTv .

So as an act of despair I decided to give it a try and it worked!
Add a `category` tag to the intent filter. It's not documented anywhere:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".SimpleBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.my.BROADCAST_RECEIVED" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Hope this helps someone.